# Delegate works in controller A but not in controller B

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

This is the delegate

```
@protocol DropControllerDelegate;

@interface DropController : NSObject
   id<DropControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DropControllerDelegate> delegate;
+ (DropController*) sharedController;

@protocol DropControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)openUserButtons;
- (void)startUpload;
- (void)uploadDone;
- (void)uploadFailed;
- (void)startDownload;
- (void)downloadDone;
- (void)subFolderLoaded;
@end
```

This is the singleton code:

```
static DropController *sharedCont = nil;

#pragma mark Singleton stuff

+ (DropController *) sharedController {
    @synchronized(self)     {
        if (!sharedCont)
            sharedCont = [[DropController alloc] init];
        return sharedCont;
    }
    return sharedCont;
}
```

The code to set the delegate is (in both myControllerA and myControllerB):

```
DropController* dropHelper = [DropController sharedController];
dropHelper.delegate = self;
```

I'm able to receive the calls in one controller but not in the other controller (the code is a copycat), this is driving me crazy!

Comment: If thats a singleton then you are overriding the delegate set previously.

Comment: What do you mean in your *other* controller? Looks like you are calling a singleton.

Comment: the singleton isn't a problem, i have another shared object with delegate that works like a charm.

Comment: I have 2 controllers that need to receive callings from the DropControllerDalegate, the first works as expected, the second don't and I can't figure why because the code is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said in my comment, since you are using a shared instance of that object, it will overwrite the previously set delegate to the new object. So i would suggest to hold a array in your sharedController. Add objects to that array which will want to become the delegates to the sharedController.

Then iterate through that array and call the method over each object in it. Its pretty simple.

---

Edit:

When you assign the delegate in your `viewcontroller A` with the statement `dropHelper.delegate = self;` object A becomes the delegate. Calling the method `[delegate openUserButtons];` will trigger the method in `viewcontroller A`. But when you do `dropHelper.delegate = self;` in viewcontroller B, `[delegate openUserButtons];` will call the method in object B. It will not call both the methods from a and b. Since there is only one delegate variable and you are using a shared singleton object.

Comment: I would say, its more like a broadcast message but with a for loop.

Comment: and probably a candidate for using notifications to solve rather than delegate.

Comment: I edited the question and added the singleton stuff, just to be more clear

Comment: Shared + Delegate have never caused problems

Comment: Can you explain how when you assign a multiple objects as a delegate to a single shared object, how can both the methods be called? Also i would like to know if i am missing something.

Comment: I figured out the problem, you right, it's impossible to receive delegate calls in 2 different controllers if a singleton is used

Comment: Do you think is doable with a second delegate in the same singleton?

Comment: Yes it works: one shared controller (singleton) with 2 different delegates, if someone need the code to do it just ask :)

Comment: How? I am guessing having a array of delegate objects which is what i have suggested in my answer.